# change value random elements of 2d array that is taken as argument in a function

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, undefined, sudoku

I want to pass testArray and replace random elements in the array with null but it's not working.
it is showing error in this part `array[v][u]= w;`

```js
var testArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
]
const num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

let pokingHoles = function(array, holes) {

  for (var i = 0; i < holes; i++) {

    var v = num[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    var u = num[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];

    const w = null;
    array[v][u] = w;

  }

}

pokingHoles(testArray, 5)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have any errors in it when run as a snippet

Comment: The code as-is shouldn't produce an error as long as you pass the array and the number of desired holes to the function. But there'll be a problem if the input is any different - you're assuming that the number of items in the outer array exactly matches the number of items in the inner arrays. If that ever changes, doing `var u =num[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];` won't be selecting a random inner item properly.

Comment: You want to get the index of a random nested array first: `const v = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);` and then get a random index from that array next: `const u = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr[v].length);`. Finally assign `null` to that index.

Comment: there was no return in this function that's why it was not working